# Select and pagination object to form group in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, pagination

I tried to group a select and pagination into one form group, but the pagination was placed at the bottom, instead of to the right. How can I solve this?

```
<div class="input-group">
<select class="form-control input-group-addon">
    <option>Egy</option>
    <option>Kettő</option>
    <option>Három</option>
</select>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms8rywns/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it without pagination and use regular buttons instead:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control input-group-addon">
        <option>Egy</option>
        <option>Kettő</option>
        <option>Három</option>
    </select>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default">1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">3</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">4</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">5</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/xPUlqlg3LK